# How do I find the exact sum of this series?

Tags: summation, factorial

I have been given the series below and I can't figure out how to get an exact sum for it. I can't derive it because of the $2n!$ in the denominator. I don't see how it can be turned into a geometric series or arithmetic. Any ideas?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}{\pi}^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$

Comment: Have you tried comparing it to the Taylor series for the cosine?

Comment: The Maclaurin series for cosine is indeed very similar and I didn't know that. 

Would that become $2cos(x)$ because of the $1/2$ in the denominator of the series?

Comment: The 2 is in the denominator of the series; the 1/2 is in the numerator of the series.

Comment: Right again, but do I multiply the 1/2 out to get $f(x) = 2cos(x)$?

Comment: Just compute the first few terms of this series and compare to the cosine series.  You should find a common factor, which is not $2$.  There is also no $x$ in your sum-you need to figure out what to substitute in for $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the Maclaurin series for cosine is given by
$$ \cos(\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\theta^{2n}. $$
Rewriting your series, we have
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \pi^{2n}}{2(2n)!}
= \frac{-1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)} \pi^{2n} $$
(observe that we have factored out a $-1$ from the numerator of each term, and a $2$ from the denominator of each term).  Comparing this to the Maclaurin series, we have
$$
\frac{-1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)} \pi^{2n}
= -\frac{1}{2} \cos(\pi)
= \frac{1}{2}.
$$